# remove version string query except for main style.css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I tried to remove all version string query except for main stylesheet because I often update the stylesheet, and I want it refreshed everytime it's updated (by manually adding its version)

Here's how I remove the version

```
function vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {
    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
```

How can I add exception, so main style.css will still show its version

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple check for `style.css` not in current source file, It will remove all `ver` query string from source file except from `style.css`

```
function vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {

    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) && !strpos( $src, 'style.css' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
```